# What are the downsides of having a large number of convolutional filters

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, filter

This question is purely about a single convolutional layer in a neural network - not about the number of layers.

Aside from computational time *what are the downsides of increasing the number of convolutional filters in a given layer?*

My intuition would be the risk of overfitting the data - for a fixed training data size, increasing the number of parameters means you increase the risk of overfitting. However if a method is used to combat this (a high percentage of dropout on the input for example) then it seems unlikely that overfitting would be a problem.

So when I want to make a network... should I have as many filters as I can handle computationally?

Answer (score 1):

> However if a method is used to combat this (a high percentage of dropout on the input for example) then it seems unlikely that overfitting would be a problem.

Actually, dropout doesn't always suffice to compensate for the increased overfitting resulting from the addition of CNN filters. E.g., from {1}:

[image]

---

References:

- {1} Dernoncourt, Franck, and Ji Young Lee. "[Optimizing neural network hyperparameters with gaussian processes for dialog act classification.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08703)" In IEEE Spoken Language Technology Workshop (SLT), pp. 406-413, 2016.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Obviously the heatmap is skewed by the logarithmic scale on the vertical axis, but you are correct. Still, if doubling the number of filters mean you have the increase the dropout by 0.1 (eg 50 - 100 filters at an original dropout of 0.2) then you can still get a significant increase in number of filters at what really just comes down to computational time. I don't see this as a problem.